# SQLite database consuming standby memory

Tags: windows, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Is there any way to control how an SQLite database is part of Windows' standby memory?

I have a service constantly reading/writing to an SQLite database based on inter-process requests.  It turns out, Windows is putting the entire database file into standby memory (I used RamMap to confirm this).

When my service is configured to allow the database to grow to a large size, say 10GB or more, the operating system becomes overtaxed.  And again, RamMap shows the 10GB+ database file in standby.

I'm using `System.Data.SQLite` for the SQLite API, and use the following pragmas:

```
PRAGMA synchronous=OFF;
PRAGMA journal_mode=MEMORY;
PRAGMA read_uncommited=True;
PRAGMA temp_store=MEMORY;
PRAGMA cache_size=10000;
PRAGMA busy_timeout=50;
PRAGMA threads=8;
```

Comment: ["Standby Memory" is just Windows' disk cache.](http://serverfault.com/questions/565539/huge-amount-of-standby-memory-in-resource-monitor) The fact that large amounts of it are in use should not be a problem.

Comment: Ok fair enough. But how come SQL server data files don't show up in standby memory like this?

Comment: SQLite always uses normal file accesses; SQL Server can decide to bypass the file cache.